# Change the color of specific heading in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, scope, angularjs-scope

I am trying to change the color of the specific heading in AngularJS. My issue is that there are multiple headings with the same class in it and I would like to change the color of the one that is clicked only. Currently, I  have tried:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span6">
        <div class="heading">Heading 1</div>                     
    </div>
    <div class="span1">
        <i class="pull-right" expand="check" collapse="close"></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
scope.setExpandCollapse = function () {
    if (scope.expand && scope.collapse) {
        if (isOpen) {
            angular.element(document.querySelectorAll('.heading')).removeClass('color-change');
        } else {
            angular.element(document.querySelectorAll('.heading')).addClass('color-change');
        }
    }
};
```

The issue is that it changes color of all the headings due to `querySelectorAll`. Is there a way for me to do this without changing my HTML?

Comment: You should use an ID for heading var yourelement = angular.element( document.querySelector( '#elementID' ) );

Comment: I believe the return of `querySelectorAll` is a NodeList which you can loop through... Try a for each or for in on `document.querySelectorAll('.heading')`

Comment: Is there any other way? like in jquery we have (this) to do so

Comment: In pseudo: loop though nodelist; if elem isOpen remove class, else...  You want to select an individual node, not all of them.

Comment: @user4756836 Could you mark the question as answered if it answered your question?

Answer (score 1):

There's many ways to solve this. Here's one:

If you trigger the click that toggles the expanded/collapsed view using `ngClick` directive, you'll have access to the `$event` of that click action. If you have the event, you can simply reference `$event.target` (origin of the click) and toggle class directly on it.

In template:

```
<h1 class="heading" ng-click="$ctrl.toggle($event);">
  Heading
</h1>
```

In controller:

```
this.toggle = function($event) {    
  $event.preventDefault(); 
  angular.element($event.target).toggleClass('color-change');
};
```

### Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/upt4jpbx/).

Edit: if you're attaching a click handler on certain elements, it's useful to add `$event.preventDefault();` to prevent any default actions that would be attached to such elements (i.e. button submitting a form). Since you probably don't want to remember which elements might do something nasty, it's safest to always have `preventDefault()` on your events, unless you explicitly want to allow the default action to take place.

Answer (score 0):

For this you'll have to create a directive as in AngularJS you are not "allowed" to touch the DOM outside them.

**JS**

```
yourAngularApp.directive('changeColor', function(){
    return {
        restrict : "A",
        link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
            elem.bind('click', function() {
                element[0].classList.toggle('color-change');
            });
        }
    };
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span6">
        <div class="heading" change-color>Heading 1</div>                     
    </div>
    <div class="span1">
        <i class="pull-right" expand="check" collapse="close"></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

The previous code is aware of a click on the element where the directive is applied and toggles (adds or removes) the class 'color-change' on click.